# How can I install web components in firefox?

Tags: camera, web-browsers

**I want to show in Firefox my cameras** (Hikvision) but web components are needed, I've tried enabling it in the Firefox configuration page but it doesn't work.

I've seen some support for another Linux distributions:

[Europe hikvision's web components for linux](http://www.hikvisioneurope.com/portal/index.php?dir=Software/02%20%20%20Web%20Components/Multi-brower%20web%20video%20componet%20for%20linux%20v3.0.3.9%20build120630_en/)

But those should not work for the Raspberry Pi.

So, I'm asking if anyone from here knows a way to do it or at least a different way to put the camera's main stream in Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install this package [webcomponents-3.0.3.9.deb](http://www.hikvisioneurope.com/portal/index.php?dir=Software/02%20%20%20Web%20Components/Multi-brower%20web%20video%20componet%20for%20linux%20v3.0.3.9%20build120630_en/ubuntu%2010.04/&file=webcomponents-3.0.3.9.deb)

```
wget http://www.hikvisioneurope.com/portal/index.php?dir=Software/02%20%20%20Web%20Components/Multi-brower%20web%20video%20componet%20for%20linux%20v3.0.3.9%20build120630_en/ubuntu%2010.04/&file=webcomponents-3.0.3.9.deb
dpkg --install webcomponents-3.0.3.9.deb
```

Comment: That doesn't work, the file is for ubuntu, not debian/raspbian, and it gives me an error.

Comment: what does the error output says? please post a log from the install process

Comment: Well, basically the architecture is not supported. dpkg: error processing archive webcomponents-3.0.3.9(2).deb (--install):
 package architecture (i386) does not match system (armhf)

Comment: then you need to ask hikvision for a webcomponents compiled for armhf i cant find some like that but you have not a big change, web components is used by many suppliers and i dont see any armhf variation.